# Sending Emails as a "batch execution job"

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I do not have any experience in web based development(neither client side nor server s ide code). since long time i had a question as to if anything like below is possible to do:

1.) I have say 10 attachments 1.zip to 10.zip on my desktop.

2.) I need to send all of these as an attachment using any web based email (I need to send out these mails using my gmail)

3.)At a time lets say i can attach only 1 file. 1.zip per email(attachment size limitations)

4.)At present i have to do the task of sending these files as attachments, repeatedly with lot of manual intervention, i.e. attach one file, type the sender email id, and click send. Wait till the email is sent(It takes around 4-5 minutes for the email to be sent) Then attach second file, and repeat the steps above.

5.) So i was wondering if is it possible to automate this process by somekind of Plugin/Code extension to:-

a.) Internet Explorer

b.) Mozilla firefox (greasemonkey based extensions)

Answer (score 1):

This will be the responsibility of the webmail client you are using.

Mutiple uplaods are possible, but only if the web app you are using can deal with them. If you are using Gmail, I'd submit a feature request to them.

The best way would be to use an IMAP email client (thunderbird, outlook express) to send your emails rather than web mail.

Comment: To clarify your point, @goldenmean should use Firebird or Outlook express to connect to the webmail account, and use that "thick client" to send the emails.